# Press Youtube Subscribe Form Button

Tags: javascript

I try to write a JS code that press the Subscribe button from a Youtube Subscribe Form.

Here is a link to a Youtube Subscribe form: http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_widget?p=aaaa

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById("subscribe-button").getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
```

But it gave me this error:

```
/*
Exception: document.getElementById("subscribe-button") is null
@Scratchpad:1
*/
```

This is the button HTML code:

```
<button role="button" id="subscribe-button" class="action-initiator yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default" type="button" onclick="controller.subscribe(null);return false;"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">Subscribe </span></button>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The element with id `"subscribe-button"` does not exist. Check if it is present on the page

Comment: See the edit. I added the button HTML code.

Comment: document.getElementById("subscribe-button") IS the button. You could call click() instantly

Comment: Oh, THANK YOU! @rene. If you add an answer, I am happy to mark it.

Comment: Are you going to make people subscribe to you without them knowing it? :O

Comment: Maybe? ;)) Programming is so nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("subscribe-button") IS the button.
```

You could call click() instantly

Comment: Thank you! It works. can you say me how to press this button when this is in a iframe? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043331/press-youtube-subscribe-form-button-inside-of-iframe