# Press Youtube Subscribe Form Button inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I am searching how to press the Subscribe button from Youtube Subscribe Form, but I didn't find anything that can help me... I am new in JS, so I hope that you will help me.

For pressing Subscribe button [here](http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_widget?p=aaaa), I use this code:

```
document.getElementById("subscribe-button").click();
```

Now my question is how to press subscribe button when this is placed in a iframe like bellow?

```
<html>
<body onload="">
     <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_widget?p=aaaa" name="iframesub" 
       style="overflow: hidden; height: 105px; width: 300px; border: 0;" 
       scrolling="no" frameBorder="0">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. The Javascript safety policies do not allow crossdomain access to the document of an embedded (i)frame.

Comment: Do you have a documentation from where you took this information? Thank you for answer.

Comment: William Fortin already answerde gave the answer ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Ok, I understood. You answered first, so I mark your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to manipulate the content of an external i-frame. It is called the [Same Orgin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You are going to need to ask the user to click on the button.

That would be a really bad practice to click on button without user's consent.

--EDIT--

If you want to subscribe the user to your channel without the user clicking on the button, read the documentation about the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions#Adding_a_subscription) on how to subscribe a user to a channel. That's your best bet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Then there isn't a possibily way to press that button without asking the user? (using another programing language)

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your question.