# Automatically press a button from iframe

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page that have an iframe. This iframe has a button. Which is one of the possibile ways to press that button?

I tried with javascript, but I didn't solve it...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: the users have to do it themselves(manually)

Comment: Note that you can't do much with an iframe, especially if it is on a different authority (site/port/etc); this is to prevent security problems with "site A" using the user's browser to talk to a different site, "site B" (maybe a bank, for example) for malicious purposes.

Comment: @MarcGravell AMEN! But I am not sure if this is possibile... Can you post an answer that helps me?.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I tried to say: it all depends on whether the iframe is for the same site. If it is for a different site, you can't do much at all with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey you can try to find that button id and handle the click event..
it will look something like this.

```
$('#youriframeid').contents().find('#yourbuttonid').click(function(){});
```

**EDIT**
 Your main html page containing iframe.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script>
 $('#a').contents().find('#iframbtn').click(function(){alert("It Worked!")});
 $('#a').contents().find('#iframbtn').trigger('click');
</script>
</head>
<iframe id="a" source="a.html">

</iframe>
</html>
```

Your second html page containing iframe mark up

```
<html>
<input type="button" id="iframbtn"  value="clickme"/> 
</html>
```

Comment: What programing language is this? I am beginner. How can I implement this in my HTML code?

Comment: Please edit your answer with an html example that has this code. :) If it works I will be happy to mark your answer.

Comment: It seems that you didn't understand my question... I want that the script press that button... Your script detect when I press that button.

Comment: please see this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043331/press-youtube-subscribe-form-button-inside-of-iframe it seems that your code doesn't work for youtube subscribe button...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
   $("#mainiframe").contents().find("someID").trigger("click");
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me... Please edit your answer with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sample1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    </HEAD>
    <script>
    function call(){
    try{
    document.frm.but.click();
    }catch(e){
    }
    }
    </script>
    <BODY onload ="call()">
    <iframe src="Sample2.html" name="frm" width=100 height=100 />
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Sample2.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    </HEAD>
    <script>
    function called(){
    alert("---DONE--");
    }
    </script>
    <BODY>
    <input type="button" name="but" value="submit" id="but" width=60 height=60 onclick="called()" />
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Does it work for you? For me not... I will be happy to mark your answer if it works. ;)

Comment: I get this exception: TypeError: document.frm is undefined

Comment: Ya its works fine for me.. just create the two HTML with the given names(Sample1.html and Sample2.html).. and try invoking Sample1.html from IE